# Navigating and passing record Id to LWC on App page from Standard Record page

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-apps, lightning-record-page

I want to be able to navigate from a record page say Opportunity to an app page which contains LWC component. I want to pass the opportunity ID to one of the LWC component so that it can work in that record context. When tried using a button it doesn't pass the ID and strips all the URL parameters.

Any help in this regards is appreciated.

Comment: How are you doing the navigation? What kind of button? What code do you have so far? It's not clear how we can help you without knowing more about what you're doing.

Comment: It is a normal standard Action button. I am trying to build a custom UI that have some filters and filter should prepopulate based on the data from the opportunity record. So it is basically a parallel way to using /apex/vfpage?id=<recordid>

However, in this case my page is not a VF page but an App page which has bunch of  LWC components. Hope that clarifies.

Comment: @sfguy Have you been able to resolve this issue? If so, can you please post the solution. I am also trying to open an AppPage from a record page. A link on the record page opens the App Page that contains an LWC component that requires the recordId of the record on the record page. Is there a way we can pass the recordId as a parameter to an App Page? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We might need a little more context to help your exact situation, but your url parameters are getting stripped if they are not namespaced. By default you would use the "__c" namespace.

You need to specific parameters like `c__parameter=xxxx`

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring19/release-notes/rn_forcecom_general_namespace_prefix_cruc_reminder.htm